# RoR - Missing Keys in Hashes inside of URL Parameter Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, parameters

I am creating a series of link_to’s, and I am passing some nested information as an array into each URL. My desired outcome looks like so:

```
?features%5B%5D%5BThick%5D=98&features%5B%5D%5BThin%5D=99
//For some legibility
?features[][Thick]=98&features[][Thin]=99
```

However, the keys to the hashes inside of the array are not showing up, and I am instead seeing:

```
?features%5B%5D%5B%5D=98&features%5B%5D%5B%5D=99
//For some legibility
?features[][]=98&features[][]=99
```

The erb that is creating this series of URLs is here:

```
<% @products.each |product| do %>
<%= link_to "", new_line_item_path(product_id: product, features: [product.features.each{|feature| {feature.name.to_sym => feature.feature_color_default}}])%>
<% end %>
```

Is this just a syntactic mistake or is it because I am taking the wrong approach?

**Perhaps this is too much information for this issue but Products have many Features which in turn have many Colors through Feature_Colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the above wasn't working but I made the following changes and am all set. Hopefully the keywords here help someone else if they are making the same mistakes.

First, I pulled the hash creation out into the Product model, like so:

```
def default_features
  list = Hash.new
  features.each do |feature|
      list[feature.name] = feature.feature_color_default_id
  end
  return list
end
```

Then I changed the link_to:

```
<%= link_to "", new_line_item_path(product_id: product, features: [product.default_features])%>
```

Working as desired now.